# Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID 'executable-jar-with-dependencies' not found

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I can't resolve this error, can you helpe me ?
This my code to pom.xml
Thank you for your help ! I'ts very complicate for me to resolve this bug

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    com.parkit.parkingsystem.App
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>executable-jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```